# How to set focus in an input element after submit and reset form?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put focus() on nameInput field after submitting the form but instead focus is on priceInput field, how can I fix this ?

```
  purchaseForm.onsubmit = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const name = nameInput.value;
  const price = Number(priceInput.value);
  if (name !== '' && price !== '' && price > 0) {
    purchases.push({
      id: nextId++,
      name: name,
      price: price,
    });

    createElement(name);
    nameInput.focus();
    purchaseForm.reset();
  }
  if (name === '') {
    messageEl.textContent = '"Input field can't be empty"';  
    nameInput.focus();
  } else if (price === '') {   
    messageEl.textContent = '"Input field can't be empty"'; 
    priceInput.focus();
  } else if (price < 0) {  
    messageEl.textContent = ''"Input field can't be empty"';
    priceInput.focus();
  } else if ([price === '""']) {    
    messageEl.textContent = '"Input field can't be empty"';
    priceInput.focus(); 
  }
  if (price > 0) {
    messageEl.textContent = '';  
  }
};
```

Comment: can you try focusing inside a setTimeout of 0 ?

Comment: why would I need  a setTimeout  in the first place ?

Comment: would you mind creating a jsfiddle link for this so we can check ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus

Comment: @AkshayBhat https://jsbin.com/gizagejaho/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @AkshayBhat could you provide your feedback please?

Comment: @Siyavush you first convert price to number, then compare it to empty string. It will never run therefore

Comment: Use template literals for your error messages. they are much cleaner. read the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: The issue is not with the error message, i have modified the message in my original project, the problem lies in focus on the nameInput when I submit the form . Focus is set on priceInput here which I need to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the jsbin link.

Here is the updated solution after submitting it is focusing on nameInput now.

https://jsbin.com/xilitewabi/2/edit?html,js,output

```
 else if ([price === '""']) {
    messageEl.textContent = '"Значение поля не может быть пустым"';
    nameInput.focus();
  }
```

The issue was in your else if statement. After submitting you were focusing on `priceInput` instead of `nameInput`

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have a problem here:

```
messageEl.textContent = '"Input field can't be empty"';   //sets the error message if name input is string and puts focus on the name input field.
    nameInput.focus();
  } else if (price === '') {   //sets the error message if price input is empty and puts focus on the price input field.
    messageEl.textContent = '"Input field can't be empty"'; 
    priceInput.focus();
```

Mind your ' and "" first of all. Your error string is terminated in the middle of the string.

I have taken your code and it works actually

```
purchaseForm.onsubmit = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const name = nameInput.value;
  const price = Number(priceInput.value);
  if (name !== '' && price !== '' && price > 0) {
    purchases.push({
      name: name,
      price: price,
    });

    nameInput.focus();
  }
}
```

When I submit form the focus is on name input.

About your conditions. Some of them do not make sense at all. I've narrowed them and again it works

```
purchaseForm.onsubmit = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const name = nameInput.value;
  const price = priceInput.value;
  if (name !== '' && price !== '' && price > 0) {
    purchases.push({
      name: name,
      price: Number(price),
    });

    nameInput.focus();
  }

  if (name === '') {
    messageEl.textContent = "Input field cannot be empty ";  
    nameInput.focus();
  } else if (price === '') {
    messageEl.textContent = "Input field cannot be empty "; 
    priceInput.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: those were just comments that messed up the code , but I have no problem with the error string , my main issue is not being able to put focus on nameInput field

Comment: well it doesn't work , perhaps because of those if conditions I guess

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been trying to say from the very beginning. Fix your ' and '' since .focus() methods that you have inside conditions never run and are definitely affected

Comment: Fixed them but still no luck , would you mind taking a look at the whole code here? https://jsbin.com/gizagejaho/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You first convert price to number and then compare it to empty string. The code block will never run since number will never be an empty string.

Comment: Those conditions I set are important for the project , you have obviously removed them and set only one condition for empty values. , this doesn't work like that

Comment: In the first place, there is no sense to check if price is equal empty string if you already converted it to number. Empty string will be 0, not ''. Next, else if ([price === '""']) - what is this condition for? What exactly does it do? Next, you already check if price > 0 in condition where you push object to array. Btw obviously you need to convert price in condition like this Number(price) > 0

Comment: That was my mistake to convert price to number, it is already a number.  else if ([price === '""']) means I am specifying that  price should not equal to string during input and should throw an error for the user.  if price> 0 is  to let the error string be empty when an input is  bigger than 0

Comment: Inputs are always strings. You just take a string and parse and convert it afterwards. But there is no sense to check if input is string.